# How to fix error when fetching file from firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, fetch, firebase-storage

I am trying to make a page that lets you upload a file and search for certain values in it, but when I am trying to fetch the file from firebase storage it is giving me an error

> Access to fetch at 'theurl' from origin 'mysite' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Yes, I have tried to set the mod to no-cors, which kinda works but the fetch returns a blank txt file. Here is my code, please help. Thanks

```
storageRef.child('thefilepath').getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
    document.getElementById("atextbox").value = url
})

var dictionaryurl = document.getElementById("atextbox").value

fetch(dictionaryurl)
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(t => {mycodethatrunsafter});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a server issue. You need your server (at Firebase?) to allow access from the domain your are trying to upload/download the file. If the Firebase server is not of your own, you'll need an anti-CORS proxy in behind, whether owned by you or one of the publicly accessible. An anti-CORS proxy takes a request with an URL in it (for example, in a HTTP GET or POST variable) and makes the request to the desired server. Finally, sends the response to the original client, with the correct HTTP headers (without CORS or with CORS rules allowing the domain).

#### Edit

To configure your Firebase Storage, follow [this](https://wp-api.agiratech.com/how-to-fix-cors-issue-in-firebase-storage/):

> Step 3: Configure Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)   We can use
> the gsutil cors command to configure CORS on a bucket:

```sh
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://mlc-agira-271a8.appspot.com
```

`cors.json` will contain:

```json
  [
   {
     "origin": ["yourapp.url.com"], // Or * if you want to allow every one
     "method": ["GET"], // And/or POST, PUT or whatever you use
     "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
   }
 ]
```

Comment: Recommendations?

Comment: Is the server on your control?

Comment: It is the firebase storage console, so kinda

Comment: Here are mine:  rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write
    }
}

Comment: Edited with info about Firebase

Comment: @KaleKo Please, also up vote the answer ;)